# Is it possible to exit out of binding.pry without a console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, binding, server, pry

Say I have the following code:

```
<% #do something
binding.pry
#do something else %>
```

Ordinarily I'd have to type "exit" into my rails server and press enter in order to move past the line "binding.pry". Is it possible to move past it without using a terminal window? By pressing a button on the page or something?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible. When `binding.pry` entered, your runtime was invoked by Pry and into the Pry session. The thread of your runtime was blocked, nothing you can do except type `exit`